# Angular ng-repeat stay paged after filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm using AngularJS and I have a simple table using ng-repeat and filter. When i insert anything at the search input it filters OK but it keeps paginated as it was before I filter the table. Any ideas why this is happening ?

Here's my code:

```js
//some var initialization
$scope.pagina = {};
$scope.pagina.currentPage = 1,
$scope.pagina.numPerPage = 10,
$scope.pagina.maxSize = 5;

//return from server with data
coresFactory.getCores().then(function(response) {
    $scope.tabelaCores = response.data; 
    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.tabelaCores.cores.slice(0, 10);
});

//do pagination
$scope.$watch('pagina.currentPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.pagina.currentPage - 1) * $scope.pagina.numPerPage),
    end = begin + $scope.pagina.numPerPage;
            
    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.tabelaCores.cores.slice(begin, end);
},true);
```

```html
<input ng-model="pesquisaTabela" type="search" style="width:300px;" class="form-control input-inline" placeholder="" aria-controls="sample_1"></label>
<table class="table" style="margin-bottom:5px;border:1px solid #DDDDDD" id="sample_1">
 <thead>
  <tr style="background-color:#F9F9F9">
   <th style="width:100px; text-align:center;"> Id </th>
   <th> Nome </th>
   <th> Plural </th>
   <th style="width:100px; text-align:center;"> Ativo </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="cor in filteredTodos | filter:pesquisaTabela" ng-click="setSelected(cor.id)" ng-class="{linhaSelected: cor.id === idCorSelecionada}">
   <td style="text-align:center;"> {{cor.id}} </td>
   <td style="text-transform:capitalize"> {{cor.nome}} </td>
   <td style="text-transform:capitalize"> {{cor.plural}} </td>
   <td style="text-align:center;">
    <span ng-if="cor.status=='sim'" class="label label-sm label-success"> Sim </span>
    <span ng-if="cor.status=='nao'" class="label label-sm label-danger"> Não </span>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<pagination first-text="<<" last-text=">>" next-text=">" previous-text="<" ng-model="pagina.currentPage" total-items="tabelaCores.cores.length" max-size="pagina.maxSize" boundary-links="true"></pagination>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a disconnect between various parts

Pagination is working off of one array, display from another and `filter` from yet another because when `filter` kicks in it returns a new filtered array.

The way you have things structured, your filter won't work properly either.
When you slice the main data array the filter is only going to work on that part that is sliced....not the whole main array

In order for pagination to be synchronized with filtering your simplest start point would likely be do your own filtering and share the same filtered array between the pagination and the table.

There are some other built in filters that you could use also like [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) that takes 2 arguments `limit` and `begin`. That would help you get rid of currrent `slice`

There are lots of available grid/table directives available.
Using one of those would be my best suggestion

There is one other way you could do this all in the view. There is a syntax for `ng-repeat` that creates a new filtered array on the scope and therefore gives you access to it's length

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in filteredData = ( data |filter:pesquisaTabela | limitTo:10:start)">
```

Using this you could pass `filteredData` array to the `total-items` of the pagination directive.

It also now lets you do things like:

```
<div> Filtered length is: {{filteredData.length}}</div>
```

Comment: Yeah man, thank you for the well explained answer. I've just created my own filter, got rid of the slice and things started to work a lot better. Thank's again.